# How could I add more android emulator devices in Visual Studio for Mac for Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I want to add some new virtual devices for Android using Visual Studio for Mac so I could use them with Xamarin. I've followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=macos&pivots=macos but surprisingly I only have the Nexus series (One, S, Galaxy, 7, 4, 10) in my Base Devices 
[image: My Base Devices]

while MS Documentation also has Pixel etc. 
[image: Screenshot from Microsoft Docs]

In OS I've APIs 21 to 28 installed.

1. How could I add more devices there?
2. Is it possible (next to Pixel) to also get e.g. Samsung Galaxy S3 to S10 into the list so I could easily create an emulator using the Galaxy S10 specs.

Comment: 1. You can create any device you want. These are base devices you can use for a foundation of whatever you want to build. If you're creating something outside this list, use a generic one instead. 2. It is not possible as we only expose the base devices that Google provides. I do not believe this is in the list found from `avdmanager list device`

Comment: There's a number of sites that show device specs such as size, resolution, and more that you can use to create an emulator for it.

Comment: Maybe supply a link or two - or this answer is useless

Answer (score 4):

Just choose whatever device you want and adjust the preferences (size, memory, resolution etc.). Don't forget to change the name of the device so you can easily choose it.
You can find info about a specific phone on Google.

If you want to add Samsung S10 open this [page](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s10-9536.php) and copy values to you VS4Mac

Comment: Yes, Jon already answered that in the comments above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this as I couldn't add one Android Device Emulator from Visual Studio for Mac / Device manager. I had to go to Android Studio / AVD Manager => Added the hardware profile from there.